# How to find the minimum of the $a^2+b^2+c^2+a+b+c+ab+bc$

Tags: inequality

(1): Let $a,b\in R$, Find this minimum of the value $a^2+b^2+ab+a+b$

I have prove $a^2+b^2+ab+a+b\ge-\dfrac{1}{3}$

(2): Let $a,b,c\in R$, find the minimum of the value
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+a+b+c+ab+bc$$
 I think when $a=b=c=-\dfrac{1}{3}$ one gets a minimum.

(3): How to find the minimum $n>1,x_{i}\in R$
$$M=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x^2_{i}+x_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}x_{i+1}$$For specific n, for example, n=2, I can get: $\min{M}=-\dfrac{1}{3}$

But in above generalized problem, how can I solve that ? Can I get the result by using sage or mathematica ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT1: as Macavity pointed out the mistake, I correct solution. 
hint :
$2M=(x_1+\dfrac{1}{2})^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i+x_{i+1}+\dfrac{1}{2})^2+(x_n+\dfrac{1}{2})^2+ 2M_{min}$

but this is only work with $n=2k+1$ for $x_i$ can get reachable number.

for $n=2k$, I got answer but I am trying to find out a simple solution.

Edit2: following is the solution.

$2M=(x_1+\dfrac{k}{2k+1})^2+(x_1+x_2+\dfrac{k+1}{2k+1})^2+(x_2+x_3+\dfrac{k}{2k+1})^2+(x_3+x_4+\dfrac{k+1}{2k+1})^2+(x_4+x_5+\dfrac{k}{2k+1})^2+...+(x_{n-1}+x_n+\dfrac{k+1}{2k+1})^2+(x_n+\dfrac{k}{2k+1})^2+2M_{min}$

Comment: Doesn't work for $n=3$, does it? Check the coefft of $x_2x_3$ for e.g. to see where it goes off...

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\\& a^2+b^2+c^2+a+b+c+ab+bc\\&=a^2+(1+b)a+b^2+c^2+b+c+bc\\&=\left(a+\frac{1+b}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1+b}{2}\right)^2+b^2+c^2+b+c+bc\\&=\left(a+\frac{1+b}{2}\right)^2+\frac 34b^2+\left(\frac 12+c\right)b+c^2+c-\frac 14\\&=\left(a+\frac{1+b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\left(b+\frac{1+2c}{3}\right)^2-\frac 34\left(\frac{1+2c}{3}\right)^2+c^2+c-\frac 14\\&=\left(a+\frac{1+b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\left(b+\frac{1+2c}{3}\right)^2+\frac 23\left(c+\frac 12\right)^2-\frac 12\\&\ge -\frac 12\end{align}$$

The equality is attained when $a+\frac{1+b}{2}=b+\frac{1+2c}{3}=c+\frac 12=0$, i.e. $a=-\frac 12,b=0,c=-\frac 12$.

Hence, the minimum of $a^2+b^2+c^2+a+b+c+ab+bc$ is $\color{red}{-\frac 12}$.

($a=b=c=-\frac 13$ does not give the minimum.)

Comment: Nice,+1, but  generalized problem seem not easy

Comment: @ConĐườngNghệ: I agree. (You may want to change the title.)